# Занести Image в БД

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ado.net

Нужно занести данные в таблицу с Image.
Она расположена в pictureBox и не отправляется в бд.
Возникает исключение:

> Не удалось преобразовать значение параметра из Bitmap в Byte[].

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Image Files(*.JPG; *.PNG)|*.JPG; *.PNG|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        try 
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);               
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Невозможно открыть данный файл");
        }
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectString);
    myConnection.Open();           

    string post = textBox1.Text;
    int sale = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    string ob = textBox3.Text;
    Image img = pictureBox1.Image;

    string sql1 = "INSERT INTO Vacancy(Post, Salary, Image) values(@post, @sale, @img)";
    string sql2 = "INSERT INTO Duties(Obligation) values(@ob)";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql1, myConnection);
    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, myConnection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@post", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@salet", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;
    command2.Parameters.Add("@ob", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = pictureBox1.Image;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/554455/12888024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы сохранить изображение в БД, его нужно преобразовать в массив байтов. Делается это стандартно через `MemoryStream`.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(memoryStream, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
    command.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

При чтении из БД нужно выполнить обратную трансформацию. Только не спрашивайте в комментариях, как это сделать! Задавайте новый отдельный вопрос при необходимости.

Обратите внимание на `SqlDbType.Binary`. Дело в том что тип `image` является устаревшим и будет [удалён](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
На заметку: тип `image` в БД совершенно не равнозначен типу `Image` в WinForms. Просто у них совпадают названия.

---

В вашем коде множество проблем. Попробую разобрать некоторые из них.

Ресурсы нужно освобождать. Для этого используйте `using`. Зачем? Со временем поймёте. Пока действуйте, как советую.

---

Давайте говорящие название всем своим переменным.
Что такое `button1`? Какое действие выполняет эта кнопка? Судя по коду, сохраняет данные в БД. Вот и назовите её `saveButton`.
Что такое `textBox1`? Судя по коду, из него берётся некое значение `post`. Вот и назовите его `postTextBox`.
И так далее. Пикчабоксу тоже дайте нормальное название.

Значение `sale` - число. Поэтому лучше использовать компонент `NumericUpDown` вместо `TextBox`.

---

`SqlDbType.VarChar` - возможно, его нужно заменить на `SqlDbType.NVarChar`. Потому что `varchar` предназначено для неюникодных символов. Если у вас допустимы русские буквы и вообще символы других алфавитов, то нужен тип `nvarchar`. Но я не знаю, какие именно данные у вас вводятся, поэтому смотрите сами.
В таблицах БД должны быть соответствующие типы.

---

Кроме того, давайте используем асинхронность. Это увеличит отзывчивость интерфейса.

---

Ну и последнее. У вас в коде вызываются две команды `insert`. Возможно, их следует обернуть в транзакцию, чтобы, если вторая не удалась, то и первая откатилась. Но я не знаю ваш сценарий использования, поэтому оставил как есть.

---

Вот итоговый переработанный код:

```
private async void saveButton_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        string sql1 = "INSERT INTO Vacancy(Post, Salary, Image) values(@post, @sale, @img)";
        string sql2 = "INSERT INTO Duties(Obligation) values(@ob)";

        using (var vacancyCommand = new SqlCommand(sql1, connection))
        using (var dutiesCommand = new SqlCommand(sql2, connection))
        {
            vacancyCommand.Parameters.Add("@post", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = postTextBox.Text;
            vacancyCommand.Parameters.Add("@sale", SqlDbType.Int).Value = saleNumericUpDown.Value;

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(memoryStream, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
                vacancyCommand.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            dutiesCommand.Parameters.Add("@ob", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = obligationTextBox.Text;

            await vacancyCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            await dutiesCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли